# Looping through a unique_ptr collection outside of an object

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to loop through a collection of pointers inside the object `Baz` from outside the class by having the class return an `vector::iterator`. When I run the `for` loop I get the following error:

`'const class std::unique_ptr' has no member named 'getName'`

Can someone explain what's going on and how I can manage to loop through the unique pointer collection inside baz? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class BaseInterface
{
protected:

std::string Name;

public:

virtual ~BaseInterface(){}
virtual void setName( std::string ObjName ) = 0;
virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class Foo : public BaseInterface
{
public:

void setName( std::string ObjName )
{
    Name = ObjName;
}

std::string getName()
{
    return Name;
}

};

class Bar : public BaseInterface
{
public:

void setName( std::string ObjName )
{
    Name = ObjName;
}

std::string getName()
{
    return Name;
}

};

class Baz
{
    protected:

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr< BaseInterface > > PointerList;

    public:

    void push_back( std::unique_ptr< BaseInterface > Object )
    {
        PointerList.push_back( std::move( Object ) );
    }

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr< BaseInterface > >::const_iterator begin()
    {
        return PointerList.begin();
    }

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr< BaseInterface > >::const_iterator end()
    {
        return PointerList.end();
    }

};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{

std::unique_ptr< BaseInterface > FooObj( new Foo() );
FooObj->setName( "Foo" );

std::unique_ptr< BaseInterface > BarObj( new Bar() );
BarObj->setName( "Bar" );

std::unique_ptr< Baz > BazObj( new Baz() );

BazObj->push_back( std::move( FooObj ) );
BazObj->push_back( std::move( BarObj ) );

for( auto it = BazObj->begin(); it != BazObj->end(); ++it )
{
    std::cout << "This object's name is " << it->getName() << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first dereference your iterator:

```
std::cout << "This object's name is " << (*it)->getName() << std::endl;
//                                       ^^^^^
```

Comment: I tried *it as well but I suppose I forgot about the parenthesis. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: A minor follow up but I thought `->` would dereference `it` already. This confuses me so much sometimes since at times only one `*` is needed.

Comment: @Tek: an iterator to a `unique_ptr` is "like" a double pointer, thus you have to dereference it twice: one to get from the iterator to the `unique_ptr` stored in the container, another to get from the `unique_ptr` to the actual object it refers to.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks, I don't usually iterate through pointer collections so explanation that helps a lot as far as visualizing the flow.